# Bug: "We are currently offline for maintenance" page link to the blog is wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that: On the "We are currently offline for maintenance" page, the link to the blog leads to the ServerFault blog.

[image: this image shows the bad link]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the network is offline, the blog of our system administrators* is where we'll be putting "Oh my god everything's on fire!" type notices.

We don't put them on the per-site blogs as a rule, since that'd just be noise once the maintenance window is over.

<sub>*blog.serverfault.com is a bit special like blog.stackoverflow.com.</sub>